# How can i use the state to filter the data and pass it to different components in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to find a way to create a search component `<SearchBar />` and display the result array through another component `<TableData />`. I managed to build it up to a certain point but is not showing the desired result. The problem is that is not shows the data until i start typing. When the parent component first loaded or i made a refresh, the data disappeared. Also when the parent component first loads, the `filterProjects` from useState render an empty array.

How can i display all the data when the components loads ?

Here's my code block:

```
const Overview = () => {

  const appCtx = useContext(AppContext);

  // Copy the incoming data from the context
  const newFilterCopy = [...appCtx.projects];

  // Create new state for filtered data
  const [filterProjects, setFilterProjects] = useState(newFilterCopy);

  // Function that takes the input coming from the SearchBar component
  const filterFunc = (input) => {
    if (input === '') {
      setFilterProjects(filterProjects);
    }

    const resultProjects = newFilterCopy.filter((project) =>
      project.projectCompanyName.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase())
    );
    setFilterProjects(resultProjects);
    return resultProjects;
  };

  

  return (
    <div className={classes.Overview}>
      <Container>
        
       <SearchBar
          placeholder='Search project by company name'
          onInput={filterFunc}
        />

        <div className={classes.TableContainer}>
          <ExportBtn />
          <TableData data={filterProjects} />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

Comment: Why don't you set filterprojects directly "useState([...appCtx.projects])", why adding a variable "newFilterCopy"

Comment: I thought it would be better to filter the data on a copy of the original array. But even if i set the state with the original data, still not works.

Comment: Try to initialize filterProjects first with an empty array and then use useEffect to make it take the appCtx.projects elements .